mutate() swr cause "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I have a button that send request POST to API then I call mutate() when request done. but its cause error. first, I think it happen because my data is too large, but when I reduce it, error still happening.
onClick function

swr fetcher

I want to refetch data when button clicked
